# Ошибка определения Native SRS

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

При публикации на геосервере postgis-слоя, имеющего более одного поля с геометрией (например геометрия полигона и геометрия точки подписи), геосерер не определяет Native SRS, что даже с SRS handling = Force Declared вызывает ошибки неверного отображения данных объекта. В postgis версии младше 2.0 это решалось прописыванием таблицы/вьюшки в public.geometry_columns. В postgis версии старше 2 эта таблица стала автоматически генерируемой вьюшкой.

Вопрос: как решить проблему верного определения Native SRS слоя на геосервере?

Comment: Как временное решение проблемы сделал разделение слоя на несколько и прописыванием их как Layer Group, однако данное решение не является очень хорошим, ибо лишает множества функций и в целом требует много труда для публикации

Answer (score 1):

Действовать можно просто по порядку:
1. Опубликовать слой с 1 геометрией - Native SRS определится
2. Создать в таблице/представлении доп.поля с геометрией
3. В меню слоя - reload feature type